# ShouldComponentUpdate and Virtual DOM react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How does react create a new virtual DOM for a component when it is updated using a `setState()` call, even when `shouldComponentUpdate()` returns false?

Does react create the virtual DOM again for all components, even for components on which `setState()` was not called? I mean suppose `setState()` is called on child component, does react a new virtual DOM for the parent component also?

Comment: There are 2 different phases you might be confusing here. There is the render phase, and the update phase. Render phase doesn't always cause and update. http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/

Answer (score 1):

> Does react create virtual dom even when shouldComponentUpdate returns false ?

No it does not. If `shouldComponentUpdate` returns false, the re-render for that particular component and its children is not done.

> Does react create virtual dom again for all components, even for component on which setstate is not called.

It will create for those components (and its children) whose state or props have changed. But that does not necessarily mean actual DOM update will happen. Also as mentioned above if any of those components return false from `shouldComponentUpdate`, re-render is stopped for that component and its child trees.

> I mean suppose setstate is called on child component, does react new virtual d for parent component also

No. Parent causes child re-renders, not the reverse. React only re-renders that subtree. Not its roots.

That said, a re-render (Virtual DOM creation) does not always mean DOM change. If previous virtual DOM & new virtual DOM for a subtree is same, the actual DOM is left untouched.

React has explained this using a very clear and concise example in their [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#shouldcomponentupdate-in-action).

Comment: Since react always create new virtual dom on every setstate call,if some component ShouldComponentUpdate function is returning false, it mean it's render function will not get called, since it is not returning anything or it's render function is not called, what does new virtual dom at particular dom node contain, as per my understanding virtual dom is creating using JavaScript object return from render function of components

Comment: When `shouldComponentUpdate` returns false, React will ignore virtual DOM diffing, and keeps the actual DOM like how it was previously. Meaning nothing will change for that component. It'll be exactly how it was earlier.

Yes, you are right. Virtual DOM has JS representation of that component. Its a tree structure that contains the component's children which can be other components or DOM elements.

Comment: Yeah, It will ignore the virtual dom diffiing but does it will create new virtual dom for that component, if yes from where it will get new JavaScript object as render function is not called as ShouldComponentUpdate has return false

Comment: I mean react create new virtual dom when there is setstate call, then it's do diffing between two virtual dom, then it will apply changes in actual dom, but if component is returning false how react will create new virtual dom for that component

Comment: It will not. If component returning false, then no virtual DOM is created, no comparison, actual DOM will not be changed. Old actual DOM will be as it is.

Comment: Yeah, but suppose I have one parent component and it has two child component A and B . Suppose there is some change in parent component which pass props to child compoonents. Then in that case component A will re- render but component B will not re rendered as it's ShouldComponentUpdate function is returning false. So now react will create virtual dom from JavaScript object return from parent component and child component A , but new virtual dom will also has JavaScript object representation of component B, as it is required for comparison with next setstate call

Comment: I want to know from where will component B virtual dom will be created as it's render function will not get called

Comment: As new virtual dom will contain JavaScript object of all components bcz may be it's required for comparison when next setstate will be called,

Comment: If `shouldComponentUpdate` returns false, Virtual DOM will not be `re-created`. If its the  inital render, then it will be created to get actual DOM. But after that, no more Virtual DOM. That actual DOM will be kept forever.

Comment: @jitendrasingh : I would suggest you to please read the docs link I have shared. The React team have explained it in detail.